# How to query a entity from datastore with Namespace In golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a multi tenant application, I need to query a particular user from a KIND and From Particular Namespace.

I am able to get the values from default Namespace.the package i am using here is `"google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"`

```
q := datastore.NewQuery(ENTITYNAME).Filter("Name =", ed.Expense.Name)
    var expenses []ExpenseEntiry
    return q.GetAll(ed.Ctx, &expenses)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace value is not part of the query (it's not a property of the query). The namespace comes from the context which you pass when executing the query, e.g. to [`Query.GetAll()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll).

If you have a context (you do as you pass it to `q.GetAll()`), you can create a derivative context with a given namespace using the [`appengine.Namespace()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#Namespace) function.

For example:

```
ctx2, err := appengine.Namespace(ed.Ctx, "mynamespace")
// check err
```

And use this new context to pass to `Query.GetAll()`:

```
return q.GetAll(ctx2, &expenses)
```

It is rare that you need to create a new context with a different namespace, `ed.Ctx` should already be a context with the right namespace. So when / where you create `ed.Ctx`, you should already apply the namespace there, so you can avoid "accidental" exposure of data of other tenants (which is a major security issue).

Comment: @NagarajaSV, if it is working you also can upvote the answer.

Comment: > "It is rare that you need to create a new context with a different namespace, ed.Ctx should already be a context with the right namespace."

Would you mind to expand on this to a Go newbie like myself? The `ctx` object I get from the `http.Request` and how would that already have the correct namespace?

Comment: @dustinmoris When this question and answer was written, the context wasn't `context.Context`, but an appengine-specific context that did contain the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I Actually found how to set the namespace with the latest Go packages for the Google Firestore in Datastore mode here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/460#issuecomment-266837286

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the old lib: `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`, then you need to create the context with the namespace:

```
ctx2, err := appengine.Namespace(ed.Ctx, "mynamespace")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

But you WANT to be using the latest lib: `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`. The Namespace can be set directly on the `Query` object. This is new. You must then run the query using `datastoreClient.Run(ctx, query)`.

```
func deleteTestNamespace(ctx context.Context, namespaces string) error {

    dsClient, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, log, datastore.Config{...})
    err := dsClient.DeleteMulti(ctx, keys[i:i+chunk])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
   
    var keys []*datastore.Key
    for _, kind := range envKinds {
        // Get all keys
        query := datastore.NewQuery(kind).KeysOnly().Namespace(namespace)
        it := dsClient.Run(ctx, query)
        for {
            var key datastore.Key
            _, err := it.Next(&key)
            if err == iterator.Done {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            keys = append(keys, &key)
        }

        // Delete all records in chunks of 500 or less
        for i := 0; i < len(keys); i += 500 {
            chunk := min(len(keys)-i, 500)
            err := dsClient.DeleteMulti(ctx, keys[i:i+chunk])
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil

}

func min(num1 int, num2 int) int {
    if num1 < num2 {
        return num1
    }
    return num2
}
```